# WARNING "[something]" has no CRC

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm trying to compile a Linux kernel from source (https://github.com/UDOOboard/linux_kernel) on ubuntu virtualbox.

When I run:

```
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make modules
```

I get a bunch of warnings like:

```
WARNING: "do_sync_read" [fs/nfs/nfs.ko] has no CRC!
```

These modules aren't being built. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: No answers here but linking to this Q since they're related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594368/crc-value-for-a-symbol-in-module-symvers-is-zero.

Answer (score 1):

This thread looks related to your error message, titled: [kbuild: bogus has no CRC warning](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0408.1/2328.html):

> ```
> # 2004/08/15 11:54:27+02:00 sam@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
> # kbuild: Bogus "has no CRC" in external module builds
> # 
> # From: Pavel Roskin <proski@xxxxxxx>
> # The recent fixes for the external module build have fixed the major
> # breakage, but they left one annoyance unfixed. If CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is
> # disabled, a warning is printed for every exported symbol that is has no
> # CRC. For instance, I see this when compiling the standalone Orinoco
> # driver on Linux 2.6.6-rc3:
> # 
> # *** Warning: "__orinoco_down" [/usr/local/src/orinoco/spectrum_cs.ko] has
> # no CRC!
> # *** Warning: "hermes_struct_init" [/usr/local/src/orinoco/spectrum_cs.ko]
> # has no CRC!
> # *** Warning: "free_orinocodev" [/usr/local/src/orinoco/spectrum_cs.ko] has
> # no CRC!
> # [further warnings skipped]
> ```

From this thread if you search for "CONFIG_MODVERSIONS linux" you'll end up on this page titled: [Kernel Symbols and CONFIG_MODVERSIONS](http://www.skynet.ie/~mark/home/kernel/symbols.html). Excerpt from that page:

> **CONFIG_MODVERSIONS** is a notion thought up to make people's lives
>   easier. In essence, what it is meant to achieve is that if you have a
>   module you can attempt to load that module into any kernel, safe in the
>   knowledge that it will fail to load if any of the kernel data
>   structures, types or functions that the module uses have changed.
>
> If your kernel is not compiled with **CONFIG_MODVERSIONS** enabled you
>   will only be able to load modules that were compiled specifically for
>   that kernel version and that were also compiled without MODVERSIONS
>   enabled.
>
> However, if your kernel is compiled with **CONFIG_MODVERSIONS** enabled
>   you will be able to load a module that was compiled for the same
>   kernel version with MODVERSIONS turned off. But - here's the important
>   part folks - you will also be able to load any modules compiled with
>   MDOVERSIONS turned on, as long as the kernel API that the module uses
>   hasn't changed.

Within that page is this:

> If you only require that none of the module's symbols are exported
>   you can use the **EXPORT_NO_SYMBOLS** macro.

I'd build with this set, since I don't think you're planning to take the compiled modules from this system to any other.

**NOTE:** You can do this in either the .config file or during `make menuconfig`.

#### References

- https://www.linux.com/forums/kernel-development/module-versions